# Passing 2 database results into view

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, content-management-system

I am having some trouble passing data from 2 queries into my view.
I have a blog system on which people can comment, but i want to show the blog post at the top of my comments page.

To do this I figured I would just pass the results from a query that retrieves the data for the blog entry.

The problem is that I can't acces the array from the view it seems like.

My code so far.

Controller

```
public function blog($page){
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $this->load->model("model_get");

    $config['base_url'] = base_url('main/blog/');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->model_get->getBlogcount();
    $config['per_page'] = 5;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data["results"] = $this->model_get->getBlog($config['per_page'], $page, "desc");
    $this->load->view("content_blog", $data);
}

function comments($page){
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $this->load->model("model_get");

    $config['base_url'] = base_url('main/comments/'.$this->uri->segment(3).'/');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->model_get->getCommentcount();
    $config['per_page'] = 5;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data["blog"] = $this->model_get->getBlog(1,6, 'asc');
    $data["results"] = $this->model_get->getComments($config['per_page'], $page);
    $this->load->view('content_comment', $data);
}
```

Model

```
function getBlog($limit, $start, $sort){
        $this->db->order_by("id", $sort); 
        $results = $this->db->limit($limit, $start)->get('blog');

        if ($results1) 
        {
            return $results->result();
        }else{

        return FALSE;
        }
    }
function getComments($limit, $start){

        $this->db->from('comments');
        $this->db->where('blog_id', $this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->db->limit($limit, $this->uri->segment(4));
        $this->db->order_by("id", "desc"); 
        $results = $this->db->get();

        if ($results) 
        {
            return $results->result();
        }else{

        return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

View

```
foreach($results as $row){
        $text = $row->text;
        echo "<p>". $text ."</p>";
        $name = $this->model_get->getUserById($row->author);

        echo "<h4>". $name[0]->login ."</h4>";

    }
```

Comment: Are you facing any error?

Comment: what is  $data1? and what you want to get please be more specific

Comment: have you tried to make a join instead of making 2 query ?

Comment: I don't have any error, I wan't to show the blog entry on wich was commented on the comments page. About the join, how would that work? I have 2 tables, one table is called blog with just the id, title, and text. the other table is called Comments with the id, blog_id, text and author.

Comment: what is $data1? answer @RakeshSharma question

Comment: Sorry, I tried to name the $data array from the second query something else to make it accessable.